# Explanation of this answer?

Tags: ruby

In the Bastardsbookofruby, this is showed as an example problem in the enumerable section.. Can someone walk me through this answer? The |a, i| part is confusing to me. Also, why are each with index and map both used? What does the i and a represent in particular?

Exercise: Practice each_with_index and map

Using the previously used ark array (['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'goat']), create a new array in which every second element is uppercased and backwards.

Solution

```
ark = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'goat']
 ark2 = ark.each_with_index.map do |a, i|
   if i % 2 == 1
      a.capitalize.reverse
   else
      a
   end
 end   
puts ark2.join(', ')
#=> cat, goD, pig, taoG
```

Comment: please refer to documentation of Array.

Comment: Also look up the Ruby syntax for "blocks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #Define the initial array
 ark = ['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'goat']
 ark2 = #Define a new array
    ark.  #by using the initial array
      each_with_index.  #loop on it with an index (1)
          map do |a, i|   #loop in the list and replace the result (2)
               if i % 2 == 1  #on every 2nd entry   (3)
                  a.capitalize.reverse  #return the string in capitals and reverse order
               else   #else
                  a     #return the result
               end
 end   
 puts ark2.join(', ')  #Print the result, separated by comma,
#=> cat, goD, pig, taoG
```

(1) `each_with_index` results in

```
[["cat", 0], ["dog", 1], ["pig", 2], ["goat", 3]]
```

(2) in each loop a is cat, dog..., `i` is the loop counter (0..4).

(3) `i % 2` is a modulo operation (reminding part of a division).
Example: `5 % 2` is 2, rest 1. The rest 1 is the result you get.

### An alternative coding:

```
 ark2 = ark.each_with_index.map do |a, i|
   i.odd? ? a.capitalize.reverse : a
 end
```

or (my favorite)

```
 ark2 = []
 ark.each_with_index do |a, i|
   ark2 << (i.odd? ? a.capitalize.reverse : a)
 end
```